# PostgreSQL/dblink: send a query with a condition on a text parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

I am trying to write a function sending a query to a foreign database using dblink, but I need to put a condition on a text column and it does not work.
It looks like this ;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dblink_test(param VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS TABLE (...) AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM dblink_connect('myconn', ...);
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM dblink('myconn',
        format('SELECT * FROM someTable where name= %s', param));
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But it return an error like `column "param" does not exist` and it is really annoying. How am I supposed to do this ?

Comment: From the snippet, I cannot figure out why it does not recognize the parameter as a variable. Anyways, you will need to quote it for the SQL-command-string. Use ```quote_literal(param)``` for this.

Comment: Ah, wait... The ```"param"``` from your error is your actual input to the function, I guess, and not a static string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format function will give you on input `'abc'` something like:

`SELECT * FROM someTable where name= abc`

But you want to check for a string literal, thus you need to quote the string (just as usual in SQL). I recommend using `quote_literal()` (to avoid SQL injection):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dblink_test(param VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS TABLE (...) AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM dblink_connect('myconn', ...);
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM dblink('myconn',
        format('SELECT * FROM someTable where name = %s', quote_literal(param)));
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```